# Google apps script : Flatten a range of formulas

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to flatten a range of formulas that I just set before.
I am using the copyValuesToRange but it dos not work... the formulas remains.

`

```
  var range = mainSheet.getRange(4,4,10,1);
  var formule = "=A4";
  range.setFormula(formule);

  var range = mainSheet.getRange(4,4,10,1);
  range.copyValuesToRange(mainSheet, 5, 5, 4, 14)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```js
  var range = mainSheet.getRange(4,4,10,1);
  var formule = "=A4";
  range.setFormula(formule);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var range = mainSheet.getRange(4,4,10,1);
  range.copyValuesToRange(mainSheet, 5, 5, 4, 14)
```